# Can a user edit state in the React DevTools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, state-management, react-state-management

It's very late so this is gonna be a quick question and I do apologize if it doesn't seem entirely coherent but I'm going to try.

I'm working on a ReactJs app, and here's the scene:

If a user goes to (requests) their own profile, a `create post` form is rendered, if they visit someone else's profile however, the form isn't rendered. Currently I'm managing this through conditional rendering, by setting the `state` to `access: read-only` if a user isn't on (/hasn't requested) their own profile, or not setting `this.state.access` (which effectively makes it `null`) if they're on their own profile page.

The issue is that if I simply change the `state` to `null` in the DevTools on someone else's profile, the form gets rendered.

I know I can disable DevTools in production, but I was wondering if there is a way to mitigate this, or even just a better way of accomplishing this, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Consider anything on the front-end always vulnerable to manipulation.

Comment: not sure if I understand the issue. Even if they're able to toggle the state of the create post form, they're not able to edit someone else's posts unless they're authenticated as them right?

Comment: @adamz4008 well yeah, unless they're authenticated as someone else, they can't post as them or edit their posts. This is mostly about being able to toggle states to change what's displayed on the screen.

Comment: @AaronSummers Sorry, didn't think so but had to make sure :). I'm still not sure what the issue is. Like you mentioned, you can just disable Devtools in prod if you don't want people to be able to use the Devtools. Are you asking if that's considered a bad practice? I don't think it is, a lot of large apps like Slack and Outlook have it enabled in prod.